# Stone-Weierstrass theorem and partial fraction decomposition

Tags: real-analysis, spectral-theory, partial-fractions, weierstrass-approximation

I'm reading notes about spectral theory and at some point it is stated that the $\mathbb{C}$-linear span of the functions $f_{\lambda}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}:x\mapsto (x-\lambda)^{-1}$, where $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$, is dense in the space $C_{0}(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{C})$ of continous functions vanishing at infinity, for the supremum norm $\Vert\cdot\Vert_{\infty}$.
It should be a consequence of the (locally compact version of) the Stone-Weierstrass theorem.
I therefore write $A:=\text{span}\left(\{f_{\lambda} : \lambda\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}\}\right)$, and try to prove that $A$ is a subalgebra of $C_{0}(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{C})$.

If $\lambda\neq\mu$, then by partial fraction decomposition we have
$$f_{\lambda}f_{\mu}=(\lambda-\mu)^{-1}f_{\lambda} + (\mu-\lambda)^{-1}f_{\mu}\in A.$$
However, when $\lambda=\mu$, how do I decompose $x\mapsto f_{\lambda}(x)^{2}=(x-\lambda)^{-2}$ as an element of $A$ ?

Comment: Indeed, $A$ is not a subalgebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not true that $f_\lambda^2\in A$.  However, $f_\lambda^2$ is in the *closure* of $A$, which is good enough to conclude that the closure is a subalgebra and thus all of $C_0(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{C})$ by Stone-Weierstrass.  To prove this, just note that $f_\lambda^2$ is uniformly approximated by $f_\lambda f_\mu$ as $\mu$ approaches $\lambda$.